# How to make Intellisense or auto complete working with Python?

Tags: python, autocomplete, intellisense

For example, the following code not working for [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
df.loc
```

[image: In PyCharm]

[image: In VsCode]

Comment: Check your pandas version.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, @selcuk. But after I update them, now I have the newest Pandas(0.25.1) , Numpy(1.17.2), and VsCode(1.39.1), the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me with bellow:

In my environment installed in **C:/Users/zmanh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages**, I could write in the following form.

```
// In vscode open : settings.json
{
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:/Users/zmanh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages"
  ],
}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this will help . But this has been a problem for a long time, and then my vscode went back to normal on its own, I'm not sure where I hit it and it was fine (I always use portable mode)

Answer (score 0):

For VS code editor, there is an extension that I installed on my editor that takes care of that. Check it out via https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: Thank you! but I have used it.

Comment: Did you install the pandas in a virtual environment?

Comment: No, I didn't use the virtual environment all the time.